# Network discovery does not find Samba?

Tags: samba

I have a simple Samba server set up with the following `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
workgroup = MYWORKGROUP
netbios name = MYNAME
server string = Samba server
server role = standalone server
hosts allow = 192.168.0. 127.
log file = /usr/local/samba/var/log.%m
max log size = 50
wins support = yes

[homes]
comment = Home
browseable = no
writable = yes
```

Samba runs and I am able to connect via IP address. I am able to see both `smbd` and `nmbd` processes running. There is no firewall installed and my client is running on the same local network as the server. Both `log.nmbd` and `log.smbd` logs show no errors.

But, I am unable to see the server under network discovery.

What could be the problem and how could I diagnose further?

Comment: What IP addresses are your client and server using?

Comment: @roaima They are DHCP-assigned. 192.168.0.100 and 192.168.0.101. Why would this matter?

Comment: It matters because you have applied a "hosts allow" restriction. Looks good, though

Comment: Can you access the server directly - not using network discovery, but by an explicit name?

Answer (score 1):

Samba does not have a Network Discovery server, see here for one:
https://github.com/christgau/wsdd

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu (22.04 at least):

```
sudo apt install wsdd
```

just works.  It installs a Web Service Discovery service which by default listens on all non-loopback interfaces.  You can edit `/etc/default/wsdd` to change that.